# Append React Component to DOM

Tags: reactjs

I want to append a React Element via Code to the friendList. How is this working?
Thanks for your help.

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o3HJ.png

Comment: I would suggest checking out `web dev simplified` react tutorials, he explains this very clearly.

Answer (score 1):

In react, your shouldn't be appending anything to anything. This should be handled in state.

```
const [friends, setFriends] = useState([]);
```

and then map over the friends in your render.

```
{ friends.map((friend) =>
  <div key={ friend.id }>
    <span>{ friend.id }</span>
    <span>{ friend.name }</span>
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: And of course you can have the `friends.map(......)` inside a component named `<FriendElement />` (or even better-`FriendsList`)